# Put last term of each sub-array of a multidimensional array to a list

Tags: python, arrays

I have a multidimensional-array like shown below.
I want to pop all elements at the last and append them to a separate list.

For eg : -

```
array([[[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14]],        # pop this row [13 ,35, 14]

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34]],        # pop this row [9,61,34] 

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34],
         [ 54, 127, 105]],        # pop this row[54,127,105]

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34],
         [ 54, 127, 105],
         [ 92, 170, 141]],        # pop this row and similarly other rows below... 

        [[ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34],
         [ 54, 127, 105],
         [ 92, 170, 141],
         [ 19,  88,  73]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31],
         [194, 185, 180]],

        [[  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31],
         [194, 185, 180],
         [  8,  32,  14]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152],
         [206, 188, 181]],

        [[ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152],
         [206, 188, 181],
         [  1,  38,  18]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70],
         [ 56,  51,  49]],

        [[ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70],
         [ 56,  51,  49],
         [ 49, 141, 112]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  8,   5,   4]],

        [[147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  8,   5,   4],
         [103, 103, 101]]]])
```

I tried slicing technique but not happening.

If I convert this array to a list ( named train) and run the code:-

```
for i in range(len(train)):
    for j in range(len(train[i])):
        for k in range(len(train[i][j])):
            train_x.append(train[i][j][k][:-1])
            train_y.append(train[i][j][k][-1])
```

I thought it would work but didn't worked.
Can anybody check the code or give an alternate method for this.

The output should be:-

train_x:-

```
      [[[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14]],         

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34]],        

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34],
         [ 54, 127, 105]],      # this continues below....

        [[ 13,  35,  14],
         [  9,  61,  34],
         [ 54, 127, 105],
         [ 92, 170, 141]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2]],    # I have edited till here but it goes on like this
 
        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31],
         [194, 185, 180]],

        [[  2,  14,   2],
         [216, 192, 173],
         [111,  58,  31],
         [194, 185, 180],
         [  8,  32,  14]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152],
         [206, 188, 181]],

        [[ 27,  41,  30],
         [209, 194, 192],
         [181, 156, 152],
         [206, 188, 181],
         [  1,  38,  18]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70],
         [ 56,  51,  49]],

        [[ 42, 105,  90],
         [ 59,  49,  46],
         [ 73,  75,  70],
         [ 56,  51,  49],
         [ 49, 141, 112]]],


       [[[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0]],

        [[  0,   0,   0],
         [147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  8,   5,   4]],

        [[147, 149, 150],
         [ 20,  22,  22],
         [  0,   0,   0],
         [  8,   5,   4],
         [103, 103, 101]]]]
```

train_y should be list of removed elements.

Comment: Remember a numpy array is an immutable object.

Comment: `train_x.append(train[i][j][k][:-1])` Shouldn't this be `train[i][j][k][-1]` instead of `train[i][j][k][:-1]`.

Comment: No, because if you see the output of train[0][0][0] : -  [[ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0],
       [13, 35, 14]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a 4-d array.
To get only the last "rows" as you describe in your comments, you only need to iterate the first 2 dimensions, and in the 3rd dimension take only the last element (no need to iterate over `k`, just use `-1`), and not index the 4th dimension at all:

```py
for i in range(len(train)):
    for j in range(len(train)):
            train_x.append(train[i][j][:-1])
            train_y.append(train[i][j][-1])
```